# Does there exists a recursive algorithm that does not fall in divide and conquer strategy?

Tags: algorithm

I am in search of an algorithm that can not be solved using divide and conquer strategy and reason why that can not be solved from it?

Comment: Are you looking for a _problem_ that cannot be solved using divide and conquer? Or are you looking for an algorithm that does not use divide and conquer? Or both?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, a recursive algorithm is a divide-and-conquer algorithm, although the division may not necessarily produce equal-sized subproblems.

As for a problem that cannot be solved using a divide-and-conquer strategy, you can trivially choose an undecidable problem, such as the halting problem, for which no algorithm of any kind exists.

Comment: `"By definition, a recursive algorithm is a divide-and-conquer algorithm"` - I'm not sure I agree with that. For example, I don't think anyone's ever called depth-first-search a divide-and-conquer algorithm. Or whether any tail-recursive algorithm would classify.

Comment: A division into size-1 and size-n-1 problems is still a division, although I agree divide-and-conquer usually refers to division into problems of roughly equal size.

Comment: I think it's only divide-and-conquer if the problem is divided into two or more *distinct* subproblems, resulting in a tree of recursive calls. A counter-example is factorial, which yields a single chain of calls rather than a tree.

Answer (score 0):

This site, http://gonitsora.com/algorithm-types-and-classification/, lists 7 basic types of algorithms, of which divide-and-conquer is one.

Pick any problem that isn't solved by divide-and-conquer, for example, the Traveling Salesman problem (visiting n cities via the shortest route) or the Knapsack problem (filling as many things of a given weight and value into a knapsack of a limited size). You couldn't solve a Traveling Salesman problem by dividing the cities in half and figuring out the shortest route for the half. Divide-and-conquer won't work because the problem is not divisible that way.

The Knapsack problem uses a greedy algorithm, and will not work by divide and conquer (either cutting the knapsack size in half or dividing the objects into two halves. It would cost too much, computation wise, to recombine them.

Comment: There is a difference between a problem having no *known* divide-and-conquer algorithm to solve it and a problem being provably unsolvable by any divide-and-conquer algorithm.

Comment: Agreed, and it was not unintentional that I picked classic problems for counterexamples. I think the OP (or his/her instructor) was looking for an intuitive reason why divide-and-conquer wouldn't work, not a formal proof.

Answer (score 0):

Although both have clever implementations which are O(log n) for input n, the straight-up implementations of Fibonacci or calculating integer powers of a base are essentially using iteration rather than divide and conquer. Ditto for the recursive version of factorials.